# How to add a dynamic drop down list in RDLC reports in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I have to Load an RDLC report in WPF application and need to include a drop down list in report.Based on the selection of drop down list different reports to be generated.I am using C# and WPF.

Eg: I have to list the details of employees in in RDLC report.There is a country drop down list, Based on the selection of country drop down list we need to display details of employees in the selected country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an analysis on this.We couldn't add a dynamic Drop down list inside the report viewer.It should be outside the report viewer.
I had created an RDLC file and added a WPF window to display the RDLC Report.I added the combo box outside report viewer in XAML file. Please see below code.

```
<Window x:Class="CAREERS.BundleManagement.App.Reports.FollowUpReportExaminer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FollowUpReportExaminer" Height="600" Width="800"
        xmlns:report="clr-namespace:CAREERS.BundleManagement.App.Reports" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>India</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">USA</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>UK</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <report:ReportViewer Grid.Row="1" ></report:ReportViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

We can load combo box dynamically by calling method sepcified in the **Loaded** event of the combo box. by calling SelectionChanged event we can load report based selection